# Java InetAddress.getAllByName() not returning IPv6 address on Windows even with -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true

Tags: java, windows, dns, jvm, ipv6

My DNS contains two records for ServerA:

- an A record with its IPv4 address: 10.25.46.130
- an AAAA record with its IPv6 address: fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55

I am not able to get my *SimpleClient.java* program *(source at the end of this post)* on a Windows server to list the IPv6 address of *ServerA* using `InetAddress.getAllByName()`, even when configuring the JVM with `-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true`.

The same test running on an IPv6 enabled Linux server is successful.

Configuration details:

- Windows: Server 2019 Standard (10.0.17763)
- Java: OpenJDK 11.0.5+

The output of `ipconfig` on the Windows server shows that IPv6 seems enabled:

```
> ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.25.0.214
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fr.company.com
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::3
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : X.X.X.X::X
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X::X
```

The `nslookup` output from the Windows server is the expected one:

```
> nslookup ServerA
Server:  dns.fr.company.com
Address:  X.X.X.X

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ServerA.fr.company.com
Addresses:  fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55
          10.25.46.130
```

I am able to successfully run `ping -6 ServerA` from the Windows server:

```
> ping -6 ServerA
Pinging ServerA.fr.company.com [fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55: time<1ms
Reply from fda8:6c3:ce53:a890::55: time<1ms
```

Below is the **expected output** running from an IPv6 enabled Linux server:

```
# IPv4 (default)
$ java SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: null
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
ServerA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55

# IPv6
$ java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: true
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/fda8:6c3:ce53:a890:0:0:0:55
ServerA/10.25.46.130
```

The same test failing on the Windows server:

```
# IPv4 (default)
> java SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: null
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130

# IPv6
> java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: true
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
```

On the Windows server, the call to `InetAddress.getAllByName()` is only returning a single IPv4 address and not both an IPv4 and IPv6 address like as expected on the Linux IPv6 enabled server.

I can reproduce the same behavior on a Linux server with IPv6 disabled (grub and kernel settings):

```
# IPv4 (default)
$ java SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: null
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130

# IPv6
$ java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true SimpleClient.java ServerA 12345
preferIPv6Addresses: true
InetAddress.getByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
InetAddress.getAllByName()
ServerA/10.25.46.130
```

From these tests, I conclude that something is wrong somewhere on the IPv6 configuration of the Windows server but I don't know what.

Some notes and stuff I tried:

- Manually adding the IPv6 address of *ServerA* in *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts* results in the program to list the IPv6 address, but only this one.
- I did not find a `DisabledComponents` key in the registy for the path `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters`

Below is the code for *SampleClient.java*:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SimpleClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) return;
        String hostname = args[0];
        System.out.println("preferIPv6Addresses: " + System.getProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses"));
        try {
          System.out.println("InetAddress.getByName()");
          System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName(hostname));
          InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname);
          System.out.println("InetAddress.getAllByName()");
          for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
            System.out.println(address);
          }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody hint at something that might be wrong on the Windows server configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: For reference, I posted the same question as well on SuperUser since I don't know if the issue comes from the JVM or from the Windows configuration: https://superuser.com/questions/1719174/jvm-on-windows-not-returning-any-ipv6-address-in-dns-lookup

Comment: Since the issue can be reproduced with the same kind of test in Python this is most likely an OS related issue.
I am keeping this question opened and will post the answer if it's found in the SuperUser thread.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the network configuration of the Windows server.

The server was provisioned with two network interfaces to segregate between IPv4 and IPv6, each interface being configured to support a single network stack.

Keeping a single network interface and configuring **both** IPv4 and IPv6 on this interface fixed the issue.

More details on the SuperUser question: https://superuser.com/questions/1719174/jvm-on-windows-not-returning-any-ipv6-address-in-dns-lookup